# Products of strictly singular operators on $L_{p}[0,1]$ or on $C[0,1]$

Tags: banach-spaces

In 1970, V.D. Milman (Operators of class $C_{0}$ and $C^{*}_{0}$, Teor. Funkc. Funkc. Anal. Ih Priloz. 10(1970),15-26) proved that the product of two strictly singular operators on $L_{p}[0,1](1\leq p<\infty)$ or on $C[0,1]$ is compact. But, this fundamental paper is written in Russian and could not be downloaded. Who could give a detailed proof of this result? Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you go to a library? (In any case you should give a reference to the paper.)

Comment: Anton, I give the reference to the paper. Sorry about it.

Comment: I do not think that anyone will be willing to translate and compile the whole proof for you. You can try to look at the papers citing this paper (MathSciNet shows 20 such papers): maybe they contain generalizations. You can also check Milman's preliminary announcement which was published in Funkt. Anal. (vol. 3 (1969) no. 1, 93–94), and, I think, was translated into English.

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail. I will try to look at the papers you mentioned.

Comment: Read page 2 of my paper "Multiplication operators..." with Schechtman, which you can download from my home page.  There are enough hints there that you should be able to fill in the details and there are references to sources that contain more.  This is for the $L_p$ case.  The $C(K)$ space case can be found in books; I think Albiac-Kalton.  The point is that an operator on $C(K)$ is strictly singular iff it is weakly compact, so the Dunford-Pettis property of $C(K)$ (i.e., that the image of a weakly compact set under a weakly compact operator is compact) gives the result.